# Kafka Consumer not consuming all records in java

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I wrote a Kafka consumer to fetch all the records from the topics and then only move to the next step but it is not fetching all the records.

```
while (fetchedRecord) {

            ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(10);
            System.out.println("Waiting for Records from Party-Resolved-Update");
            Thread.sleep(40000);
            for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records) {

                System.out.println("Record fetched");
                end++;
                System.out.println(record.value());
                if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(record.value())) {
                    fetchedRecord = false;
                    response = record.value();

                    FSecurity sc = new FSecurity();
                    sc.init();
                    decryptResponse.add(sc.decryptData(response));
                    System.out.println("decryptResponse=" + decryptResponse);
                }


            }

        }
```

Comment: What is the exact behaviour? Does it fetches no message at all? Does it block at `consumer.poll()`? How did you setup your consumer?

Comment: @TobiSH It is fetching some records but not all the records.Setup consumer like:
consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(props);

Comment: And what properties do you set (That was my initial reason to ask. Sorry that I didn't make it clear)

Answer (score 0):

Please describe your problem correctly.

Assuming you are not able to consume next set of records.

*Solution*
Either provide `enable.auto.commit` as `true`, or add `consumer.commitSync()` statement explicitly in your code. This will allow you to poll the next offset records.

Comment: i know i should comment to the unclear questions. but looking at his code, i thought this might be one of the solution. will not answer to the unclear questions from next time, thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: How my code will go to next poll ? once it will go inside the for loop with some set of records than fetchedRecord variable will be True i.e exit from the while loop due to which if I again call this method then first I will get the old set of remaining records from the topic.
My requirement is in every poll it will fetch all the records from the topic

Comment: if you are going to call the method again and again, then you can add `consumer.commitSync()` inside for loop at the end, which will say the consumer that record has been consumed so that `consumer.poll()` which is triggered when you call the method again, will start from the last committed offset.

Comment: no, the requirement is in the next call I don't want the previous messages. In every call, I want the new messages.

Comment: let's say you have 100 records in your partition. you poll first 10 records for in the first poll. in the second poll you will get the same previous records if you have not committed, if you commit, meaning you add the statement that is specified in previous comment, you will be able to poll next 10 records and so on.